# WPF Datagrid format one cell based on conents of other cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a small issue with WPF Datagrid. My data grid items source in an SQL table called Case, however in the code there are several properties added to Case. One of them is ColorForTAT, which contains logic for coloring cases, however this property should not be visible for user
Untill now I managed to make it work for setting a background color for a full row, however what I was asked to do is to color only one column(Name="TimeTillTatExternal). I tried to google it but couldn't find anything working.

```
        <DataGrid Name="DataGridCase" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Row="9" Grid.RowSpan="3"  Grid.ColumnSpan="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0" SelectionChanged="DataGridCase_SelectionChanged">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="CaseNumber" Binding="{Binding CaseNumber }" Header="Case Number"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Status" Binding="{Binding FinalStatus }" Header="Tool status"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Title" Binding="{Binding Title }" Header="Title"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Country" Binding="{Binding CountryFromAssignemnt }" Header="Country"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="CreatedDate" Binding="{Binding CreatedDate, StringFormat = 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm' }" Header="Created date"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TATExternal" Binding="{Binding TATExternal, StringFormat = 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm' }" Header="Due date External"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TATInternal" Binding="{Binding TATInternal, StringFormat = 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'  }" Header="Due date Internal"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Assignment" Binding="{Binding Assignment }" Header="Assignment"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TimeTillTatExternal" Binding="{Binding TimeTillTatExternal }" Header="Days left"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Status3" Binding="{Binding LinkedIncident }" Header="LinkedIncident "/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Status4" Binding="{Binding ExternalSupport}" Header="ExternalSupport"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Status2" Binding="{Binding SDStatus }" Header="Service Desk Status"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ColorForTAT }" Value="black">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ColorForTAT }" Value="gray">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ColorForTAT }" Value="red">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ColorForTAT }" Value="yellow">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ColorForTAT }" Value="green">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set each column CellStyle and bind the Background to a static resource that you can declare at Window.Resources: Example code is shown below please alter the code according to your requirement.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" ...>
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="clBr" Color="White" />
</Window.Resources>
```

...

Columns:

```
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="Background" 
                            Value="{StaticResource clBr}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
```

then you can just manipulate the static resource by either code or xaml manipulation.